# Why would all my project files be hidden in VS2023 on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

I have a demo project I am working on, and none of the project files show up in my project, and none of the projects will build.

I am on a Windows 11 machine running the latest VS2023.

Others on my team are using VS for Mac, and they don't seem to have any issues.

Why would these files be hidden, and how can I fix it?

Screenshot below as well as the csproj file

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <Sdk Name="Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions" Version="2.1.3" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Ardalis.GuardClauses" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ardalis.Result" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ardalis.SmartEnum" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ardalis.Specification" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\dotNetDemo.SharedKernel\dotNetDemo.SharedKernel.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]